# tomcat7-maven-plugin can't find dependency from reactor

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, maven-plugin, embedded-tomcat-7

I have a product line, it has two maven modules: module A and module B

I declare module B depends on module A.

Also I define a maven reactor like this:

```
    <modules>
        <module>A</module>
        <module>B</module>
    </modules>
```

Module A is a pure Java module, Module B is a web module. 
I am trying to do integration testing, so I start tomcat7-maven-plugin 2.0 in Module B.

Embedded tomcat works perfectly If I build and install modules one by one like this :

```
    cd A
    mvn clean install
    cd ../B
    mvn clean install
```

But if I run the reactor, Embedded tomcat will complain class X is not found which is in Module A and fails to start:

```
    cd reactor
    mvn clean install
```

By the way, without tomcat7-maven-plugin, the reactor works well.

my tomcat7-maven-plugin version is 2.0

Answer (score 1):

The issue disappear when I upgraded tomcat7-maven-plugin to the latest version (2.2)